# Could not find an appender named [appender_name_IS_UNDEFINED]

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring Spring Boot :: (v2.7.7-SNAPSHOT)
I was trying to access configuration from `application.yaml` file to `logback-spring.xml` but the problem is it always shows me the error : **Could not find an appender named [appender_name_IS_UNDEFINED].** I have attached my configuration here for better understanding. Please help me I am trying to fix this last 2 days but I am failed. Thank you

**application.yaml**

```
    server:
      port: 80
    app:
      logging-to:console
    logging:
      level:
        "[org.springframework]": INFO
        "[com.med4pan.cloudapp]": DEBUG
```

**logback-spring.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/looging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
        <springProperty scope="context" name="CONSOLE_PATTERN" source="application.console-pattern"/>
        <springProperty scope="context" name="appender_name" source="app.logging-to"/>
        
        <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable</pattern>
                <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    
        <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>Cloud-Panel-Logs.log</file>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>Cloud-Panel-Logs.%d{yyyy-MM}.log</fileNamePattern>
                <maxHistory>6</maxHistory>
                <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable</pattern>    
                <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    
        <appender name="ASYNC_CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
            <appender-ref ref="${appender_name}"/>
            <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
            <queueSize>100000</queueSize>
            <includeCallerData>false</includeCallerData>
            <neverBlock>false</neverBlock>
        </appender>
    
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_CONSOLE"/>
        </root>
        <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>
    </configuration>
```

**Error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Could not find an appender named [appender_name_IS_UNDEFINED]. Did you define it below instead of above in the configuration file?
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - See http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#appender_order for more details.
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender[ASYNC_CONSOLE] - No attached appenders found.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:344)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:298)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:301)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:136)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:90)
    ... 87 common frames omitted
```

I followed [this link](http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#appender_order) given in the error message. I think I have configured the file according to the instruction but it didn't work

Comment: It can be useful to pass the parameter `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to your executing program to make the logger output debug information as it configures itself. This will indicate the configuration files it finds, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same issue when I was running tests for my spring boot application.

I added logback.xml in src/test/resources and it worked.